# How to pass cardElement to createPaymentMethod(cardElement, customerId, priceId) React+Stripe?

Tags: html, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have their `<CardSection />` element in a SignUp form component, on submit I authenticate the user, create the customer, but can't figure out how to pass the `<CardSection />` to the createPaymentMethod function.

Some of what I have: 
SignUp form:

```
handleSignUp = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let cardElement = document.getElementById('#cardElement');
    signUp(this.state.email, this.state.password, cardElement);
}
```

Where `signUp()` looks like:

```
import firebase from './firebase.js';
import { createCustomer } from './createCustomer.js';
import { createPaymentMethod } from './createPaymentMethod.js';

export function signUp(email, password) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        console.log(`Error in signUp ${error.code}: ${error.message}`);
    });

    createCustomer().then((customer) => {
        let customerId = customer.customer.id;
        let priceId = "price_HIsuBNTXc2NQ7L";
        createPaymentMethod(cardElement, customerId, priceId);
    });
}
```

This doesn't work (I get `TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.`), and I think I'm doing this plain incorrectly. What's the right way to do this part?

The documentation (https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price) seems to skip this step going from step 4 to 5. I'm pretty green with Stripe and React so take it easy on me. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your code is incomplete, the signup function takes 2 parameter but you provide 3 when you call it

Answer (score 0):

I believe Erwan Daniel's comment is correct and your `signUp` function is missing an argument.  Its signature should probably be:

```
export function signUp(email, password, cardElement)
```